# What does LogEntry do?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am just curious, because I can't find what it is anywhere online. I looked at Django's documentation and it just tells you what's inside it, I guess? I'm just curious because it is being used in some code I'm looking at and I need to know if it's important.

Here's the code I'm looking at.

```
LogEntry.objects.create(
                    user_id         = request.user.pk,
                    content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(SummerInfo).pk,
                    object_id       = SummerInfo.pk,
                    object_repr     = (request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name),
                    action_flag     = 2,
                    change_message = 'Completed/Updated Summer Intent Form'
                )
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/) logs the actions you perform with it, and internally stores them as entries via `LogEntry`. One of the ways it's directly used is for the "Recent actions" section of the admin page.

The code you're looking at adds a new entry which is then displayed in that section. This is useful if you want to make custom actions show up there.

You can see how the django admin uses it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/)

Comment: Thank you so much!